# Keras - VGG fine-tuned model gives bad predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I have this code:

```
base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(64,64,3))

# convert to sequential model
model = Sequential()
for layer in base.layers:
    model.add(layer)

# Remove last layer
model.layers.pop()

# add flatten and two dense layers that don't appear when specifying an input_shape
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Dropout(.5))

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Add a layer for 3 classes
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'rmsprop',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# training
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=64, verbose=1)

# predict
y_target = model.predict(x_target, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
```

I can't seem to understand why it gives me such a low accuracy and bad predictions. Could someone explain this to me? I am using Tensorflow.

Comment: It depends on many conditions, Input data quality, data quantity, class distributions and etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your model as it is **doesn't learn** at all.

You are using a `VGG16` pre-trained model changing top layers with new layers, for your model to learn your new classes, but later you are making **all** layers untrainable. This way, your new dense layers will always contain random weights, as their initialization, and your model will never learn.

If you want to keep your `VGG16` weights freezed and fine tune your model, you should move your freezing layers' weights code *before* adding your new layers, like this:

```
#Moved here
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# add flatten and two dense layers that don't appear when specifying an input_shape
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
...
```

Keep in mind that your model may have better results by not freezing any layers. For this, just leave all your layers be trainable.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Even with the change, the accuracy is still just below 50%. Does this mean my x_train and y_train are both bad/need to be improved? Each one has about 15,000 image data so I don't think quantity is the issue with it.

Comment: You can try several things for improvement. First if your hardware is capable, totally unfreeze all layers (remove "for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False"), try different optimizer, learning rate, epochs, augmentation...